# Developing a replacement for Sharepoint “Alert Me”-function

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, notifications, alert

I'm pretty new to sharepoint-development, so I thought I'd check real quick with the gurus in here.

I've been given the task of building a replacement for the built-in Alert Me feature. The main reason for this is to allow for alerting members of a role with a forms authenticated sharepoint.

This is where you guys come in. I know you can build an immediate Alert Me function by creating list item event receivers.

However, if I wanted to create the summary-feature (daily/weekly notifications) - what would be the best way to go about this?

With very limited knowledge, all I could think of was to create a Windows Service, which checks daily for changes to the lists, and sends notifications accordingly, in one summarized email.

Would I be wrong to assume that this is, if not the best/only way to do it, at least one way of doing it?

And could I use the SPChangeCollection to accumulate the changes?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by *alerting members of a role with a forms authenticated sharepoint*? Alerts work when you use FBA.

Comment: Yes that's right. But if you want to alert a "role" - meaning just adding the role to the alert, and not the members of this role individually, the members won't receive the alert. The built-in alert system doesn't traverse the roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create windows service: you have SharePoint job for scheduled tasks.

However, I would reconsider the need. SharePoint alerts already offer immediate/daily/weekly alerts. thos member of the role (group?) can perfectly choose the "Alert me" individually. i personnaly would consider otherwise as spam (how do you unsubscribe, then?)

Comment: It's a requirement that the members of that role are all subscribed. They'll receive the notification in a specific email account, so it won't be 'spam' per say :) besides... it's one weekly summary, I'd hardly consider that more than a very slight annoyance - if that :)

I chose to develop using the sharepoint custom timer jobs though. Thanks for your input